# Swift how to Create Multipage Form and Save Data to Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, uikit

I have successfully installed Firebase and connected the login and registration with UID. If the user saves additional data in the app, I would now like to assign this to the respective user who is logged in, what is the best way to do this? Sorry I'm a beginner in Swift and Firebase, I need a tutorial or an explanation that is not too complex.

Thank you all

- Uikit
- Swift 5
- Firebase

Comment: there is alots tutorial in websites, u can check them, here just ask ur question

Comment: I honestly just found stuff about Flutter, not ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this is assuming you have Firebase UserAuth connected with your app and setup.

All users have a UID, user identifier, that uniquely identifies them. This is easy to get.

```
//there must be a user signed in
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
let uid = user.uid
```

Simply put, to store data that is unique to the user, store it all under the uid using Firestore. If you do not have Firestore, [get started with Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

All data you save to Firestore, must be structured in a dictionary format with String as the key and Any as the value. For example, if I wanted to store the top 3 favorite flavors of ice cream for a user, you would do this *note firebase will create these documents and collections for you automatically if they do not exist so do not panic *:

```
//First get a reference to the database.
// It is best to have db as a global variable
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let favoriteFlavors: [String: Any] = ["numberOne":flavorOne as Any, "numberTwo":flavorTwo as Any, "numberThree": flavorThree as Any]

//access the collection of users
//access the collection of the currentUser
//create a document called favoriteFlavors
//set the document's data to the dictionary
db.collection("users").collection(uid).document("favoriteFlavors").setData(favoriteFlavors) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully written!")
    }
}
```

Now, when you want to retrieve this data, you do access the users collection, the collection of the logged in user, then read the favoriteFlavors document--like this:

```
let docRef = db.collection("users").collection(uid).document("favoriteFlavors")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document {
        print("Document received")
// retrieve the data in the document (a dictionary)
        let data = document.data()

    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

So if you wanted to get the number one favorite flavor, you would do this:

```
//Remember that data is a dictionary of String:Any
if let numberOneFlavor = data["numberOne"] as? String {
    print("Number one favorite flavor ",numberOneFlavor)
}
```

Granted, this can get more convoluted, but this is a solid foundation of what you need to know. I advice reading the [add data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) and [get data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) pages of the Firestore documentation.